# sdkmanager vs "android update sdk" to install dependencies

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-build

Im installing `android sdk` into my ubuntu server to build/test my projects 
there.

I need to install dependencies for the command line and I found that now you can only download `android/tools` folder from [Android download link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

There you can find `bin/sdkmanager` so I used to install `build-tools` and `platform-tools`, but found that I can use it to install android sdk versions, support repository, and others.

Whats the difference between

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-25
```

and

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Right now it looks like the same thing. But

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
```

looks better for me.

Also you can use

```
sdkmanager --update
```

to update all installed items without any additional options.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between two.
Btw there is a little type in your `sdmanager` command, platforms;android-25 should be in quotes.

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
```

Comment: Actually there is a difference. How are you going to auto accept the licenses without "--no-ui --all" ? It's not a valid option to the command sdkmanager and I don't see an alternative. It actually throws "Accept? (y/N): The following packages can not be installed since their licenses or those of the packages they depend on were not accepted:"

Comment: And there seems to be no similar valid option according to the guidelines: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#options

Comment: @Galya unlike `android`, the `sdkmanager` cmd is a command line only tool, so there's no need for the `--no-ui` option.  Similarly it installs all by default, so there's no need for `--all` either.

I could be wrong, but `sdkmanager` has never prompted me to accept a license either, but if it did then you could prefix the command with `echo y |`